# Why does GetRows() method return a transposed array?

Tags: vba, ms-word, adodb, recordset

Im using a Adodb connection
and reading the result of a query
into an array with

`array = recordSet.GetRows()`

which leads to a transposed array of dimensions

> (row,col)
>
> (0, 0)
>
> (0, 1)
>
> (0, 2)

instead of

> (row,col)
>
> (0, 0)
>
> (1, 0)
>
> (2, 0)

so it should be a 3 x 1 not 1 x 3 array
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because it is returning an Array containing (intField, intRecord):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427.aspx

So it's a matter of different interpretation in the way that intField is basically the Column and intRecord the Row (both zero-based).

Answer (score 1):

note that (using ADODB driver):

```
Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset recordset     ;does not transpose a 
                                            ;recordset
varArray = recordset.GetRows(10)            ;transposes a recordset
Range("A1:L10").Value = varArray            ;does not transposes array
listbox.list = varArray                     ;does not transposes array
listbox.column = varArray                   ;transpose array
listbox.column = recordset.GetRows(10)      ;does not transpose a 
                                            ;recordset
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations to your answer.